# Proof of probabilities that may not be independent

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

I am given the problem:

Given $P(A) = \frac{3}{4} $, $P(B) = \frac{3}{8} $, show that:

a) $P(A  or  B) > \frac{3}{4} $.

b) $\frac{1}{8} < P(A and B) < \frac{3}{8} $.

The problem does not specify that A and B are independent events, so I don't think I can just do P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B) for part a).
So I think I have to use the properties of conditional probability, but the problem also doesn't give P(A|B) and such, so I am lost as to how to solve this...

Comment: You need to add the self study tag. You need to take advantage of probability inequalities. Note that in the case of part b there would be an exact result if A and B were independent events.

Comment: If they were independent events, I could just do P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(AB), which would be in this case 3/4 + 3/8 - (3/4)(3/8) and easily solve part a) and b), but since the problem does not indicate that they are necessarily independent, I believe I have to use P(A∩B)=P(B∣A)P(A) property, which confuses me as I am not given P(B|A) in the problem.

Comment: You don't have to solve for the probability in b. You just have to develop inequalities based on that relationship. In my answer I already explained how to get the answer for part a.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see that A an B are not disjoint since P(A) + P(B) > 1. and you have the inequality that P(A or B) >= P(A). If B is not contained in A then P(A or B) would be greater than 3/4. See if you can take advantage of P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B) to get the inequalities in part b of the question.

Comment: who says B cannot be contained in A?

Comment: Alright, just to reiterate to make sure I am understanding and applying your advice correctly. For part a), because P(A) and P(B) are not disjoint, it means that there is some overlap of P(A) and P(B). By that reasoning, P(A or B) must be >= P(A) and therefore >= 3/4.

Comment: That is exactly what I am saying.

Comment: Zhanxiong is right P(A or B)  would = 3/4 if B is contained in A and nothing in the question as described precludes this.

Comment: For part b), P(A and B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A or B), which we know is > 0 as P(A) + P(B) > P(A or B). We know P(A and B) cannot exceed 3/8 as P(B) is 3/8, so for the lower bound of P(A and B)...

Comment: You mean upper bound. For the lower bound you need to show that it can't be less than 1/8.

Comment: And for the lower bound it cannot be less than 1/8 as P(A)+P(B) = 9/8, and P(A or B) cannot be greater than 1, meaning P(A) + P(B) - P(A or B) cannot be less than 1/8?

Comment: To get the lower bound note that P(A) + P(B)= 9/8.and P(A or B)<=1. So P( A and B) must at least be 1/8.

Comment: You got it write just as I submitted m last comment.

Comment: Your welcome. Maybe you can give a check to my answer. Note that none of the inequalities in parts a and b are strict.